# Enforce absolute child element to fit parent with padding

Tags: html, css

How can I force a child with absolute positioning to fit parent with padding? Absolute positioning on child is a must in my case.

EDIT: I want child to get inside parent's content box, not just fit into the box.

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="elem">

  </div>
 </div>
</body>

<style>
#wrapper{
  padding:25px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
   background-color:blue;
   position:relative;
}

#elem{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:green;
}
</style>
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wmbszuzo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `box-sizing: border-box;` and `width: calc(100% - 50px);`

https://jsfiddle.net/wmbszuzo/10/

Comment: I guess this works nice, but i also heard that calc is slow, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `width:100%`? It will default to `width:auto`, which is probably what you want in this case.

Answer (score 0):

since you have a fixed padding, you can do this

```
#wrapper{
  padding:25px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
   background-color:blue;
   position:relative;
}

#elem{
  margin: -25px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@D. Nizio try this: https://jsfiddle.net/wmbszuzo/57/

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  padding: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
 }
#wrapper:nth child {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;  
  }
.elem {position:relative; 
   padding:0px; 
   margin-right:25px; 
   background-color:green; 
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
  <div class="elem">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
       eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
       ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
       aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
       in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat 
       nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 
       in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

add to child css:

```
top:0; left:0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wmbszuzo/7/

Comment: That works, but i didnt seem to precise my problem. I want the child to fit into content box of parent.